# Filter documentlist in fileopen/filesave dialog in Word/Excel

Tags: office-integration, 2007

When opening a document from a documentlibrary in Word/Excel/Outlook the FileOpen Dialog shows all the files in the document library.

I have a lot of documents in there, with metedata in columns. How do i show those extra columns (in the fileopen/save dialogs), and how do i enable filtering of those columns?

Just finding my file based on only the filename is hard, using the metadata would be a great improvement.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can filter when opening files in SharePoint 2007. This in fact one of the new features in SharePoint 2010, where you can use your taxonomy and meta data filtering to filter amongst large amounts of data.

You should be able to filter on sub-folders though if that is a help.

Comment: We just ditched folders in favor of metadata. Which works nice in the SharePoint interface in combination with custom views and filters. However in de OpenFile Dialog it is just a big list again.